# Bug: x === y but results of a /@ x and a /@ y differ?

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching, core-language

**Bug introduced in 10.2, and persisting through 11.1**

**Bug resolved in 12.0**

---

This is strange:

```
ClearAll[x, y, a, b];
a[{{_Integer, _Integer, _Integer | PatternSequence[]} ..}] := c;
(*this is a match:*)
a[{{1, 1}}]
(*this too:*)
a[{{1, 1, 1}}]

b = CoordinateBoundsArray /@ {{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}};

x = First@b;
y = {{{1, 1}}};

x === y(*True*)

a /@ x(*{a[{{1,1}}]}*)(* this does not finish evaluating?!*)
a /@ y(*{c}*)

If[Not[
  a /@ x === a /@ y(*False*)
  ], "something is wrong"]
```

Everything works fine if I change `a` to

```
a[{{_Integer, _Integer} ..}] := c;
```

or if assign the result of `CoordinateBoundsArray /@ {{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}}` to `b`

```
b = {{{{1, 1}}}};
```

Can someone confirm this?

Comment: I get the same answer both in V11.0.0 and in V10.4.  I can't see any explanation.

Comment: It's a bug in pattern matching for packed arrays. I have filed a report.

Comment: Behavior reproduced in 10.3

Comment: I do not reproduce the problem with versions 11.3 and 12.0.

Answer (score 11):

Not a proper answer, but we can see that there is a significant internal difference between the two:

```
Needs["Developer`"]

PackedArrayQ[x]
(* True *)

PackedArrayQ[y]
(* False *)
```

Comment: And I was thinking of some even more fancy optimizations in the interpreter. Nice find!